# Whats wrong with this question?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Islam Stack Exchange post: [Am I allowed to name a baby Alan?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/77099/am-i-allowed-to-name-a-baby-alan)

Hello,
The answer chosen for this post is discrimination and voting negative without reason or argument to my posts are , I believe against the rules of the forum.

Please delete my posts and my account if this behaviour persists. I tried to be polite with my posts.

This concerns an unborn baby's life and is a violation of human rights as well.  Please review . You can take ownership of my account and post the question.

Also my profile was attacked with curious potato.  Look at his profile and comments.

Comment: User with **125 rep** are allowed to downvote, and most_don't_want_to/ aren't obligated to give a reason for their downvote in the comments/anywhere *(this is discussed in stack meta)*. However rude/offensive/derogatory responses are to be flagged/reported and will most likely be removed. As for your question it is unclear. The answer to that question doesn't completely answer the question, it should be a comment.

Comment: On further inspection, I have found that you deem downvoting as bullying/sin however the fact is I/We only downvote when a question is unclear, poorly asked or doesn't meet community guidelines. I/We appreciate and upvote question/answers that are spectacular, well_written, have a general approach and are never asked before.  I/We don't have any personal grudges with you, and certainly don't appreciate bullying/harassment.

Answer (score 1):

Adaab.

Respected @Hidden person, what actually happens that Stackexchange websites are very strict about being laser sharp focus on topic. It has its own etiquettes and practices.

Downvote hurts. But it is to sort the questions whether it is clear or on topic or useful or shows research effort, or not.

It is also recommended to a downvoter that a comment suggesting improvement of the question or the answer (explaining why the downvote) generally helpful, but the downvoter is not forced to write an explanation.

Reactions or heavily emotional statements like "delete my account" ot "take over my account" may be perceived as being disruptive. But you may fairly ask the audience about where the question need further improvement/ cleanup/ focus/ elaboration/ context etc.

Happy asking

Peace be upon you.

Comment: Have you seen the profile of curious potato he posted 'hahahahahahaha' and more . Look at his profile and do an ip address check please

Comment: I want to keep this forum sage and he abused Muslims and islam in another question asked in the forum

Comment: This was a clear violation

Comment: @Hiddenperson i am so sorry that such bad things happened to you. I do not know how to IP check etc. you can screenshot such answers and report such users.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for the poor reception you've received on this site. However, it's important to note that as a public Q&A site, we have no real way to control who posts a question, or an answer on somebody else's question.

The Internet is full of all kinds of people, and some of them enjoy lashing out at others just to hurt them. There's only so much we can do about that, but rest assured that such behaviour is absolutely against our [code of conduct](https://islam.stackexchange.com/conduct).

We rely on community curation to keep the site clean, so if anyone ever sees behaviour of this sort, it needs to be flagged immediately so the moderators can deal with it. We can only respond so fast after someone has chosen to break the rules, but we can at least minimize the harm such troublemakers can cause.